# Is this a power signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-power

$x[n]=\sin(\pi n)$

Since this is a discrete signal, and n can take only values like ...,1,2,3 ... the value of the power is getting zero, and since it gets zero does it mean that it's not a power signal?

Answer (score 1):

There a few variations on the definitions of "energy signal" and "power signal". For example, Sklar in his textook "Digital Communications" defines "energy signal" as a signal with energy $E$ such that $0 < E < \infty$, and a "power signal" as a signal with power $P$ such that $0 < P <\infty$.

However, others (see for example [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/77705/54382)) define "energy signal" as a signal with $E < \infty$.

In your case, $x[n]=0$ for all $n$; then this signal has zero energy and zero power. Whether it is classified as an energy or a power signal depends on which specific definition you adopt. For instance, if you go with Sklar's, then this signal is neither an energy signal nor a power signal.

Comment: Well, it is _both_ an energy signal (with zero energy) and a power signal (with zero power). Note that $\frac{1}{2N+1}\sum_{n=-N}^N |x[n]|^2 $ "approaches" a finite limit as $N \to \infty$ and so the signal is a power signal. That the average is _already_ at the limit $0$ when $N=0$ and just stays there forever is not germane.

Comment: Dilip, I guess there are different possible definitions. Sklar's "Digital Communications" defines energy signals as signals with finite _but non-zero_ energy, and does the same for power signals. I had this book nearby when I answered the question, so I went with his definition.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I've clarified my answer to account for the different definitions of energy and power signals.

Comment: OK, and a +1 for the edits. But I don't regard Sklar's book as definitive, and signals with zero energy are of some interest in more theoretical studies (often as counterexamples which must be carefully avoided in crafting formal definitions).

Comment: @DilipSarwate Agreed on all counts.